# Remove an external user access for a Folder/Document in a Document Library Programatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, sharepoint-rest-api, modern-document-library, external-sharing

I have shared a **folder/document to an external user (outside the organization)** in SharePoint online doc library. An email to the new user is shared with One time passcode to access the file.
Now, the requirement is to **Un-Share the document only for that user** programatically. PLease suggest me the right API and sample code piece to help me in this regard.
Any help as CSOM, REST API is appreciated TIA!

PS: I am using .NET CSOM apis and I am not sharing anonymous links to external user

Answer (score 0):

here is the script. Haven't tested. You can add sub-sites too in another foreach.

```
string WebUrl = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/web";
string UserLoginName = " i:0#.f|membership|name.surname_domain.com#EXT#@microsoft.com";

public static void RemoveUserPermissions(string SiteUrl, string UserLoginName)
{
    using (var ctx = new ClientContext(SiteUrl))
    {
        var Web = ctx.Web;
        var Lists = Web.Lists;
        ctx.Load(ctx.Web);
        ctx.Load(Lists);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Removing user {0} from Site: {1}", UserLoginName, SiteUrl));
        var User = Web.SiteUsers.GetByLoginName(UserLoginName);
        Web.RoleAssignments.GetByPrincipal(User).DeleteObject();
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (var List in Lists)
        {
            var UniqueListPerm = List.HasUniqueRoleAssignments;
            ctx.Load(UniqueListPerm);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            if(UniqueListPerm)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Removing user from List or Library: {0}", UserLoginName, List.Title));
                List.RoleAssignments.GetByPrincipal(User).DeleteObject();
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            }

            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' /></OrderBy></Query></View>";

            var Items = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
            ctx.Load(Items);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach (var Item in Items)
            {
                var UniqueItemPerm = Item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments;
                ctx.Load(UniqueItemPerm);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                if (UniqueItemPerm)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Removing user from Library {0} and Item: {1}", List.Title, Item.Id));
                    Item.RoleAssignments.GetByPrincipal(User).DeleteObject();
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it will work for external user viz. "john@gmail.com"?  Also, why we have to remove user from Site Level (external user to be removed only from a document)?  sorry..... it's just a thought

Comment: Also, what you suggest to put  at 2nd line - string UserLoginName = " i:0#.f|membership|name.surname_domain.com#EXT#@microsoft.com"; If the user is john@gmail.com

Comment: for this kind of user will be created a ext account in your tenant like : i:0#.f|membership|john_gmail.com#EXT#@yourdomain.onmicrosoft.com do you understand?

Comment: @zdenek this didnt worked for me... Throwing exception at List.RoleAssignments.GetByPrincipal(User).DeleteObject(); as User does not exist

Comment: so get var User = Web.SiteUsers and find like *john* maybe its in different format. Try find john_gmail.com#EXT#@yourdomain.onmicrosoft.com dont forget change "yourdomain.onmicrosoft.com" to your default O365 domain.

Comment: Did you help my answer? Mark it please.

Comment: this didn't helped me to remove external user permissions.. I think UserObject is changed or I am missing something. Just not able to get the user access removed

Comment: so this script work but didnt remove permissions for the user?

Comment: yes @Zd, permissions are not getting removed

Comment: user is correctly loaded?